# Kernel 4.4 and nvidia G86

Tags: kernel

I need to update the kernel to kernel 4.4 because I want to buy a Wacom CTL-490DB-S. But I have an nvidia-driver for GeForce 8500 GT running. So my question is:

Can I update to kernel 4.4 without running into problems with wiley? Actual I have a running 14.04 LTS with a kernel 3.13.0-79-generic and an nvidia-driver 340.96.

The last time, I tried to update the kernel, I didn't have a regularly screen size, only a 480-Resolution was there.

Hope, anyone could give a useful hint, what to keep in mind here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, with NVIDIA, it's kind of hit-and-miss. You can try updating to the newer version, and you shouldn't have any problems, but there's always a risk. If you keep the older kernel installed, and the new one fails, hold down SHIFT at startup to get into the GRUB menu, go into the advanced options, and choose the older kernel version so you can boot and get rid of the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install and use kernel 4.4 in Ubuntu 14.04. I am using that kernel on my Ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is that DKMS modules, like Nvidia or VirtualBox will not build for kernel 4.4 without gcc-4.9.

But that is a bit tricky. You will need to install about 20 packages from Ubuntu 15.10 or 16.04.

There are some answers at AU about how to install gcc-4.9.
If you do that, the system should run well.

Much easier is to install Ubuntu 15.10. In that case kernels 4.4 can be installed without this kind of problems.

Another option is to wait for about a month and install Ubuntu 16.04.